# Retrieving as much data as possible using two keys, one of which is corrupted

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a column to one table (some_data) from another (all_info); originally, id_a and id_b would be a sufficient foreign key and I'd use them to uniquely identify the values from table all_info to bring over to table some_data.  However, somewhere down the line *some* of the id_b's in some_data got corrupted.  Thus, I want to add a column to some_data that still uses the values in all_info when there is an exact match on id_a and id_b, or, if no exact match exists on id_a and id_b but there is only one entry for that particular id_a in all_info, we assume that's what we want (and replace the corrupted id_b in some_data)

So, given two tables,

```
some_data        all_info
id_a | id_b      id_a | id_b | val
------------     --------------------
 1   | a          1   | a    | v_i
 2   | b          2   | c    | v_x
 3   | c          2   | b    | v_ii
 4   | d          3   | d    | v_iv
                  3   | e    | v_v
                  4   | f    | v_vi
```

I'd like to obtain:

```
id_a | id_b | val
------------------
 1   | a    | v_i
 2   | b    | v_ii
 3   | c    | NULL
 4   | f    | v_vi
```

Thus far I've thought of two approaches, one of which is rudimentarily:

```
SELECT sd.*, ai.val
FROM some_data sd
LEFT OUTER JOIN all_info ai
ON sd.id_a = ai.id_a
  AND (sd.id_b = ai.id_b OR COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Of course that itself wouldn't work (and also doesn't accomplish my secondary goal of replacing the bad id_b's), but trying various groupings and selectings with the COUNT() function I couldn't find anything that SQL found agreeable enough to run with.  I thought also to try populating the column with SET commands but again couldn't find a way to make it work.

As a side note, looking at the data it seems as if all_info has AT MOST one row that matches some_data on both id_a and id_b.  Also, when id_a and id_b do match it is safe to assume that the match is correct, given the complexity of id_b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select would be something like this:

```
SELECT sd.id_a, sd.id_b, 
       CASE WHEN ai.id_a IS NULL THEN ai2.val ELSE ai.val END as val

FROM   some_data sd

       LEFT JOIN all_info ai
       ON ad.id_a = ai.id_a AND ad_id_b = ai.id_b

       LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT id_a, MIN(id_b) id_b, MIN(val) val
        FROM   all_info
        GROUP BY id_a
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
       ) ai2 ON sd.id_a = ai.id_a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run this to fix your data:

```
UPDATE some_data sd

       JOIN 
       (SELECT id_a, MIN(id_b) id_b
        FROM   all_info
        GROUP BY id_a
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
       ) ai ON sd.id_a = ai.id_a AND sd.id_b <> ai.id_b

SET    ad.id_b = ai.id_b
```